# mod rewrite from apache to nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite

I'm having some trouble in transformation of htaccess from apache to nginx.

actual htaccess rule:

```
options +followsymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|system|themes|css|js|flex|slider|rss|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?$1 [L]
```

this rule set is used in expression engine 1.7

my current solution :

```
    location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @ee;
}
location @ee {
    rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?/$1 last;
}
location /index.php {
    include fastcgi_params;
    set $script     $uri;
    set $path_info  $uri;
    if ($args ~* "^(/.+)$") {
       set $path_info  $1;
    }
    fastcgi_pass fastcgi-upstream_${server_name};
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass fastcgi-upstream_${server_name};
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

but it not reflexting 100% the same thing as in htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the location block in Nginx. This will redirect all your request to index.php.

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?$1 break;
}
```